# SQL to XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq

I am trying to pull from a SQL database and produce a formatted XML file.
Looking at previous questions, the best way to do this is using LINQ.

So far, I have the SQL data pulling back into a C# DataSet, there are two tables.
I am using the following code to try and output to an XML doc

```
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
            new XElement("Snapshot",
                new XAttribute("Date", "2018-06-04"),
            new XElement("Rooms",
                from p in data.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
                select new XElement("RoomType1",
                    new XAttribute("Rate", p["Rate"]),
                    new XAttribute("Size", p["Size"]),
                    new XAttribute("Other", p["Other"]),
                    )),
             new XElement("Cutomers",
                from p in data.Tables[2].AsEnumerable()
                select new XElement("Customer",
                    new XAttribute("CustomerId", p["CustomerId"]),
                    new XAttribute("Name", p["Name"]),
                    new XAttribute("PhoneNumber", p["PhoneNumber"]),
                    new XAttribute("Email", p["Email"])
                    ))     
doc.Save(@"c:\temp\WholeFile.xml");
```

This almost produces what I am looking for but on the second data set I want to group by the customerId, so CustomerId will only show once, then the name, phonenumber and email will all be displayed below.

I had a look at grouping using LINQ as it looks as though this is what I need to do but when I run the below code it groups by the customerId correctly but the CustomerId element is still showing on each row of data.

```
            var groups = doc.Descendants("Portfolio")
            .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("PortfolioId"))
            .ToList();

        var newDoc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("Customers",
                from e in doc.Descendants("Customer")
                group e by (string)e.Attribute("CustomerId") into g
                select new XElement("Customer",
                    new XAttribute("CustomerId", g.Key),
                g
                )
            )
        );
```

Have tried just about everything but can't work out how to pick the fields from the collection (is that the right term) "g".

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: so you are getting datatable  and then generating xml ?

Comment: Yes, that part is all working (I think) but I can't seem to format the XML as I need to.

Comment: What's your input data? What's expected output?

Comment: Change the from as follows : from p in data.Tables[2].AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => p["CustomerId"]).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())

Answer (score 0):

I personally find it way easier to create the XML on the SQL Server. Here's how I would approach this problem:

```
USE [yourDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_yourProcedure]    Script Date: today ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      you
-- Create date: today
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_yourProcedure] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @example1 varchar(50) = '',
    @example2 varchar(50) = '',
    @example3 varchar(50) = '',
    @example4 int = 0
    -- ect

AS  
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Initialize XML
    DECLARE @xml xml = (
    SELECT  

    -- Declare XML Structure
    TA.example1 AS 'example1',
    TA.example2 AS 'example2',
    TA.example3 AS 'example3',
    TA.example4 AS 'example4'
    -- ect

    -- Specify the Context of the XML
    FROM yourTable TA WHERE yourConditionFactor = @yourConditionFactor
    FOR XML PATH('yourXML'))

-- Do what you want with your @xml here
-- enter code



END
```

I find it very easy and minimalistic to define the XML structure.
You could then call the stored procedure into your c# environment by using EF and LINQ and just pass the data parameters to your procedure.
If you have multiple XML's you want to create,  just let your SP run in a foreach statement.

Hope this helps!